# Cron - Scheduling a workflow to run every hour, except 2 hours between 12 AM and 2 AM

Tags: cron, scheduler, schedule

I am using cron and I need to schedule my workflow, so that it runs every day hourly, just except 2 hours from 12 AM until 2 AM. Meaning it needs to run daily from 2 AM and kick off every hour, but just when the clock hits 12 AM it should't run for 2 hours. And then starts back at 2 AM to run every hour.
Would appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CRON job

`0 0 2-23 ? * * *`

Description: Job will start at second:00, at the minute:00, every hour between 02 am and 23 pm, of every day

I have found [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) website useful to create CRON job